# Redirecting Errors

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

**UPDATE**

I'm currently making an eCommerce website and facing an error in my **redirecting**. Normally there is no error. But whenever I login in as an admin/user I face redirecting error. Let me explain more.

**Problem:1**

I'm logged in as a user. And I want to make an online order. Then I go to the **Confirm Order** page. And if I refresh my browser it takes me to my **Profile** page. **Why am being redirected to my profile? Why not be on the same Confirm Order page? Though I settled [if(isAuthenticated===true){.....}]**

**Problem:2**

I've logged in as Admin now. And I go to the **Dashboard Page**. And there is also the same problem. If I refresh the browser it redirects me to the **Profile Page**.

Here's my **App.js Code**:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Routes} from "react-router-dom"; 
import Header from "./component/layout/Header/Header.js";
import webFont from "webfontloader";
import Footer from './component/layout/Footer/Footer';
import Home from "./component/Home/Home.js";
import ProductDetails from "./component/Product/ProductDetails.js";
import Products from "./component/Product/Products.js";
import Search from "./component/Product/Search.js";
import LoginSignUp from './component/User/LoginSignUp';
import store from "./store";
import { loadUser } from './action/userAction';
import UserOption from "./component/layout/Header/UserOption.js";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Profile from "./component/User/Profile.js"
import ProtectedRoute from './component/Route/ProtectedRoute';
import UpdateProfile from "./component/User/UpdateProfile.js";
import UpdatePassword from "./component/User/UpdatePassword.js";
import ForgotPassword from "./component/User/ForgotPassword.js";
import ResetPassword from "./component/User/RestPassword.js";
import Cart from "./component/Cart/Cart.js"
import Shipping from "./component/Cart/Shipping.js";
import ConfirmOrder from "./component/Cart/ConfirmOrder.js";
import Payment from "./component/Cart/Payment.js";
import OrderSuccess from "./component/Cart/OrderSuccess.js";
import MyOrders from "./component/Order/MyOrders.js";
import OrderDetails from "./component/Order/OrderDetails.js";

import Dashboard from "./component/admin/Dashboard.js";


import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';

function App() {

  const {isAuthenticated, user} = useSelector(state => state.user);

  const [stripeApiKey, setStripeApiKey] = useState("");


  async function getStripeApiKey() {

    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/v1/stripeapikey");


    setStripeApiKey(data.stripeApiKey);

  }


useEffect(() => {


  webFont.load({
    google:{
      families:["Roboto","Droid Sans","Chilanka"]
    },
  });

  store.dispatch(loadUser());

  getStripeApiKey();


}, [])


  return (
    
    <Router>
      
      <Header />

      {isAuthenticated && <UserOption user={user} />}
      
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
        <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
        <Route path="/products/:keyword" element={<Products />} />
        
        <Route path="/search" element={<Search />} />

        <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
        
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginSignUp />} />
        
        
        <Route element={ <ProtectedRoute isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} /> } >
          
          <Route path="/account" element={ <Profile /> } />
          <Route path="/me/update" element={ <UpdateProfile /> } />
          <Route path="/password/update" element={ <UpdatePassword /> } />
          <Route path="/shipping" element={ <Shipping /> } />
          <Route path="/order/confirm" element={ <ConfirmOrder /> } />
          <Route path="/success" element={ <OrderSuccess /> } />
          <Route path="/orders" element={ <MyOrders /> } />
          <Route path="/order/:id" element={ <OrderDetails /> } />


          <Route path="/process/payment" element={ stripeApiKey && 
            <Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripeApiKey)}> <Payment/> </Elements>} />

   
        <Route path="/admin/dashboard" element={ <ProtectedRoute isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} isAdmin={true} > <Dashboard /> </ProtectedRoute> } />
        </Route>

        

        <Route path="/password/forgot" element={ <ForgotPassword /> } />
        
        <Route path="/password/reset/:token" element={ <ResetPassword /> } />



      </Routes>


      <Footer />
      
    </Router>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here's my **Protected Route Code**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';   
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';


const ProtectedRoute = ({ isAuthenticated, children, isAdmin }) => {



    const { user } = useSelector(state => state.user);

    
        if(isAuthenticated === false) {
            return <Navigate to={"/login"} />
        }
        
        if(isAdmin === true && user.role !== "admin") {
            
            return <Navigate to={"/login"} />
            
        }
        
        return children ? children : <Outlet />

    
    }

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

**Please help me with that. And please let me know if I should have added anything more to the question. So that you can understand better. Thank You so much**

**LoginSignUp Code:**

```
import React, { Fragment, useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Loader from '../layout/Loader/Loader';
import MailOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MailOutline';
import LockOpenIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockOpen';
import FaceIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Face';
import "./LoginSignUp.css";
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { clearErrors, login, register } from '../../action/userAction';


const LoginSignUp = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();

    const { error, loading, isAuthenticated} = useSelector(state => state.user)


    const loginTab = useRef(null);
    const registerTab = useRef(null);
    const switcherTab = useRef(null);


    const [loginEmail, setLoginEmail] = useState("");
    const [loginPassword, setLoginPassword] = useState("");
    const [user, setUser] = useState({

        name: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",

    });

    const { name, email, password } = user;

    const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState("/Profile.png");
    const [avatarPreview, setAvatarPreview] = useState("/Profile.png");



    const loginSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        dispatch(login(loginEmail, loginPassword));
    }



    const registerSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const myForm = new FormData();

        myForm.set( "name", name );
        myForm.set( "email", email );
        myForm.set( "password", password);
        myForm.set( "avatar", avatar );
        dispatch(register(myForm));

    };


    const registerDataChange = (e) => {
        if(e.target.name === "avatar") {
            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = () => {
                if(reader.readyState === 2) {
                    setAvatarPreview(reader.result);
                    setAvatar(reader.result);

                }
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

        } else{
            setUser({...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        }
    };


    const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split("=")[1] : "/account";


    useEffect(() => {
        if(error){
            toast.error(error,{
                position:"bottom-center",
                theme:"colored"
            });
            dispatch(clearErrors());
        }



        if(isAuthenticated){
            navigate(redirect);
        }

    }, [dispatch, error, isAuthenticated, navigate, redirect]);
    



    const switchTabs = (e, tab) => {
        
        if(tab === "login"){
            switcherTab.current.classList.add("shiftToNeutral");
            switcherTab.current.classList.remove("shiftToRight");


            registerTab.current.classList.remove("shiftToNeutralForm");
            loginTab.current.classList.remove("shiftToLeft");
            

        }

        if(tab === "register"){
            switcherTab.current.classList.add("shiftToRight");
            switcherTab.current.classList.remove("shiftToNeutral");


            registerTab.current.classList.add("shiftToNeutralForm");
            loginTab.current.classList.add("shiftToLeft");

        }

    };







    return (
        <Fragment>
            {loading ? ( <Loader /> ) 
            :
            (  <Fragment>
                <div className="loginSignUpContainer">
                    <div className="loginSignUpBox">
                        <div>
                            <div className="loginSignUpToggle">
                                <p onClick={(e) => switchTabs(e, "login") }>LOGIN</p>
                                <p onClick={(e) => switchTabs(e, "register")}>REGISTER</p>
                            </div>

                            <button ref={switcherTab}></button>
                        </div>
                        <form className='loginForm' ref={loginTab} onSubmit={loginSubmit}>
                            <div className="loginEmail">
                                <MailOutlineIcon />
                                <input 
                                    type="email" 
                                    placeholder='Email' 
                                    required value={loginEmail} 
                                    onChange={(e) => setLoginEmail(e.target.value)} 
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="loginPassword">
                                <LockOpenIcon />
                                <input 
                                    type="password" 
                                    placeholder='Password' 
                                    required 
                                    value={loginPassword} 
                                    onChange={(e) => setLoginPassword(e.target.value)} 
                                />
                            </div>
                            <Link to="/password/forgot">Forget Password?</Link>
                            <input type="submit" value="Login" className="loginBtn" />
                        </form>

                        <form className="signUpForm" ref={registerTab} encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={registerSubmit}>
                            <div className="signUpName">
                                <FaceIcon />
                                <input type="text" placeholder='Name' required name="name" value={name} onChange={registerDataChange} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="signUpEmail">
                                <MailOutlineIcon />
                                <input type="email" placeholder='Email' required name='email' value={email} onChange={registerDataChange} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="signUpPassword">
                                <LockOpenIcon />
                                <input type="password" placeholder='Password' required name='password' value={password} onChange={registerDataChange} />
                            </div>

                            <div id="registerImage">
                                <img src={avatarPreview} alt="Avatar Preview" />
                                <input type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/*" onChange={registerDataChange} />
                            </div>

                            <input type="submit" value="Register" className='signUpBtn' />
                            

                        </form>





                    </div>
                </div>
            </Fragment>)
            }
        </Fragment>
        
    );
};

export default LoginSignUp;
```

This is the User Reducer:

```
import { 
    LOGIN_REQUEST, 
    LOGIN_SUCCESS, 
    LOGIN_FAIL, 
    REGISTER_USER_REQUEST, 
    REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS,
    REGISTER_USER_FAIL,
    LOAD_USER_REQUEST,
    LOAD_USER_SUCCESS,
    LOAD_USER_FAIL,
    LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
    LOGOUT_FAIL,
    UPDATE_PROFILE_REQUEST,
    UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
    UPDATE_PROFILE_RESET,
    UPDATE_PROFILE_FAIL,
    UPDATE_PASSWORD_REQUEST,
    UPDATE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS,
    UPDATE_PASSWORD_RESET,
    UPDATE_PASSWORD_FAIL,
    FORGOT_PASSWORD_REQUEST,
    FORGOT_PASSWORD_SUCCESS,
    FORGOT_PASSWORD_FAIL,
    RESET_PASSWORD_REQUEST,
    RESET_PASSWORD_SUCCESS,
    RESET_PASSWORD_FAIL,
    ALL_USER_REQUEST,
    ALL_USER_SUCCESS,
    ALL_USER_FAIL,
    UPDATE_USER_REQUEST,
    UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS,
    UPDATE_USER_RESET,
    UPDATE_USER_FAIL,
    DELETE_USER_REQUEST,
    DELETE_USER_SUCCESS,
    DELETE_USER_RESET,
    DELETE_USER_FAIL,
    USER_DETAILS_REQUEST,
    USER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
    USER_DETAILS_FAIL,
    CLEAR_ERROR, 
} from "../constants/userConstants"






export const userReducer = (state = {user:{} }, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {



        case LOGIN_REQUEST:
        case REGISTER_USER_REQUEST:
        case LOAD_USER_REQUEST:
            return {
                loading: true,
                isAuthenticated: false,
            };
            
            
            case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            case REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS:
            case LOAD_USER_SUCCESS:
            
                return {
                    ...state,
                    loading: false,
                    isAuthenticated: true,
                    user: action.payload
                };


                // for user Logout 
            case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
                return {
                    loading: false,
                    user: null,
                    isAuthenticated: false,
                }




                case LOGIN_FAIL:
                case REGISTER_USER_FAIL:
                
                    return{
                        ...state,
                        loading: false,
                        isAuthenticated: false,
                        user: null,
                        error: action.payload
                    };

                case LOAD_USER_FAIL:
                    return {
                        
                        loading: false,
                        isAuthenticated: false,
                        user: null,
                        error: action.payload
                    }


                    // For user logout fail

                case LOGOUT_FAIL:
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        loading: false,
                        error: action.payload,
                    }

                case CLEAR_ERROR:
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        error: null,
                    }





    
        default:
            return state;
    }


}
```

The issue Picture:
[image: Confirm Page]
[image: Profile Page]

Comment: Because i can't run your project to debug, so i did a related project about `Private Route` at this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/private-routes-5od03y?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You can refer it and then check your code.

Comment: What is the profile page? What I suspect is happening here is that the `state.user` redux state is set ***after*** the app mounts and renders, so the `ProtectedRoute` redirects to `"/login"`... then I'm just guessing here that `LoginSignUp` does another auth check on the `user` state, and now that it's populated, redirects to a default "profile" page. Please include all relevant code you are working with as part of your [mcve].

Comment: @AnhLeHoang Okay. Am gonna check the code.

Comment: @DrewReese Heyy bro. Thank you for the comment. Am updating it with the "LoginSignUp" Code.

Comment: @DrewReese hello. I updated and add the LoginSignup code. Please can you check it? and tell me why am getting this problem?

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Ok, it seems that my suspicions were correct. Here's what I believe is occurring.

1. User authenticates and navigates to a protected route, `"/order/confirm"` for users and `"/admin/dashboard"` for admins.
2. The `ProtectedRoute` checks the `isAuthenticated` and `isAdmin` props against the current `user` state and correctly renders the `children` prop or `Outlet` for the protected component.
3. User reloads the page. It's at this point I'm assuming that the redux state isn't persisted/rehydrated, in other words, the state is reset and later re-derived. On the initial render cycle:

   1. The user is still on a protected route path and the `ProtectedRoute` again checks the `isAuthenticated` and `isAdmin` props against the current `user` state. This time though `isAuthenticated` is `false` or the `user` object hasn't the "admin" role and the `<Navigate to="/login" />` is rendered and the user is navigated to `"/login"`. It's important to note at this exact moment that any queryString parameters are dropped.
   2. The `isAuthenticated` and `user` state is re-derived and set in the redux store.
4. The `LoginSignUp` component mounts and renders and at some point mentioned above the `isAuthenticated` state becomes truthy and the `useEffect` hook redirects to `"/account"` the profile page because there are not any `location.search` params.

   ```
   const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split("=")[1] : "/account";

   useEffect(() => {
     ...

     if (isAuthenticated) {
       navigate(redirect); // <-- redirect to "/account"
     }

   }, [dispatch, error, isAuthenticated, navigate, redirect]);
   ```
5. User ends up on the profile page on route path `"/account"`.

## Solution

I think the solution may be fairly trivial. Update the `ProtectedRoute` to conditionally wait for an ***explicitly*** boolean `isAuthenticated` value to effect any auth redirects or allowing access through to the protected component. This requires using an ***explicitly*** non-boolean initial `isAuthenticated` state, i.e. `undefined` or `null`.

Example:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children, isAdmin }) => {
  const { isAuthenticated, user } = useSelector(state => state.user);

  if (isAuthenticated === undefined) {
    return null; // <-- or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  if (!isAuthenticated || (isAdmin && user.role !== "admin")) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
  }
   
  return children ? children : <Outlet />;
}
```

Just ensure that the initial `isAuthenticated` redux state value is also `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. But it didn't work yet. Still facing the error. I added images and Reducer Code. Please check.
It will be really helpful. 
Again Thank you so much.

Comment: @SayedulKarim Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the routing/navigation/authentication issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: https://sk-mern-stack-ecommerce.herokuapp.com/

Comment: This the link of the website